# How to get root access to my android application?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-file

I have an application where user will take a snap from camera and view it.

For that functionality, i am creating a file in SD Card to store the returned data from camera to the created file

Whenever i am creating a directory i am getting an error.

```
com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.console.InsufficientPermissionsException
```

This is the code for creating directory.

```
 public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                MediaConstants.BASE_DIRECTORY);

        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                //Getting error here
                return null;
            }
        }

      //Code to create file name in the directory
    }
```

I got to know that my application doesn't have sufficient permission to create a directory in external storage. Please help me on giving permissions to my application to create a directory

Comment: i think you need (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />) in your manifest file

Comment: Did you mention file's related permission in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: if you add the Write Permission, you dont need to include the Read permission

Comment: Yes, i have added permissions,      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 2):

You don't need root permission to do this. Rather, you just need the appropriate file permissions:

```
 android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

You should add a `<uses-permission>` declaration for these in your manifest. In addition, for Android M, you should [query these permissions at runtime](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html) by calling [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#requestPermissions(java.lang.String[],%20int)) and [checkSelfPermission()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#checkSelfPermission(java.lang.String)) as appropriate. See also: [permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) and [saving files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) documentation.

Comment: thanks for responding, I have already provided permissions to my application in manifest file.      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Are you sure that your application actually has the permissions? In Android M and up, it is possible for the user to revoke the permissisons, even though they have been declared.

Comment: What are you seeing as the value of mediaStorageDir? Can you log which portion of that path exists or doesn't? I'm guessing you might be creating a directory at a level that simply isn't allowed with external storage permissions.

Comment: In my code you can find it that i am getting externalStoragePublicDirectory() , which is giving me the top level directory path but the problem is with the permission as the device i'm testing is ROOTED and my app doesn't have SU permission..

Answer (score 0):

Specify `android.permission.FACTORY_TEST` permission. [docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#FACTORY_TEST)

For accessing `root` permission use:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

Source : [Here](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/)